# how to split the word and get the 4 letter prefix in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

i have a username= LICTowner.

i need to get the prefix from the word LICTowner i.e LICT.

how to split the word and get the 4 letter prefix.

in asp.net using C#

Comment: is the prefix always 4 letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String userName = "LICTowner";
String prefix = userName.Substring(0,4); // LICT
String restOfWord = userName.Substring(4); // owner
```

Answer (score 5):

if the prefix is ALWAYS 4 letters you can use the `Substring` method:

```
var prefix = username.Substring(0, 4);
```

where the first int is the start index and the second int is the length.

[Substring on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

hmmmm.... before anything, a) you should really look for similar questions and b) thats not a hard problem to do... i mean, have you even tried???

if the prefix is always 4 letters, then just use  the .Substring method... as in

```
string username;
string prefix=username.Substring(0,4)// or something like that, cant remember off the top of my head
```

Comment: We'll I guess I made whomever down-voted bitter with my remarks, but they are true, i mean, just by pressing "." after username will have intellisense show you the list of methods, im sure "substring" would ring a bell...

Comment: +1 Agreed, This is such a simple thing and it has been covered before on SO as well as all over the web. Lets keep the questions on this site a little more challenging than the first day of c# 101.

Answer (score 1):

```
  string s = "LICTowner";
  Label1.Text=    Regex.Replace(s, "[^A-Z]", "");
```

Simple regular expression to remove all characters other than upper case

Answer (score 1):

```
string name="aryan";
 string prefixwords= name.substring(a,b);
//a from where you want the string 
// b till where you need the string  now take any label and print the value

 string prefixwords= name.substring(0,2);
label lblmsg= new label();
lblmsg=prefixwords.tostring();  // ary

string restofwords= name.substring(2); // an
```

Answer (score 0):

If the prefix is always 4 characters use simple substring

Else
a) remove all non upper case characters

```
 string s = "LICTowner";
      Label1.Text=    Regex.Replace(s, "[^A-Z]", "");
```

b)
split at the first non upper case character

```
   Label1.Text= Regex.Split(s, "[^A-Z]")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Substring() function to get the first four Character.

```
string mystring = "LISTowner";
string prefixword = mystring.Substring(0,4); 
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Text = prefixword;
```